# CSS 4 columns, adjust as size

Tags: html, css

I saw this page http://demo.smartaddons.com/templates/joomla3/sj-joomla3/ and was wondering how to do the same footer, when you decrease the size of the screen, the elements remain on top of one another.

I looked at the source, but did not understand me.
I do not want to use Joomla, I do pure CSS and HTML.

tks

Comment: It's called responsive, heard of it? Try bootstrap as a starter to for 10.

Comment: Media Query , Typography , Bootstrap Grids is the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a responsive page.

Using CSS3, you can set limits to the page width. And if the page reaches this limit, the style changes to accommodate the new size. In the example that you showed, there is a limit right where the screen reaches 1200px in widht and another one when it's in 979px and below.

you can set this by declaring this in your CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    /* Your code here */
}

@media (min-width: 979px) {
    /* Your code here */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The footer you are talking about mixes several css properties. But the most imporant to get the "responsive effect" are **`floats`** and **`media queries`**

You will find inforamtion about media queries [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) and float [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)